# How to calculate the value in the row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I want to add the value in row as i mentioned in the below code.

[image]

Here i have posted some sample code here.

```
Create Table #temp1
(
  ID int,
  Value Varchar(MAX)
)

Insert into #temp1 Values
(1,'0.1+0.26'),
(2,'1.1+7.25-4.65'),
(3,'2.1+6.24*3.3'),
(4,'3.14+5.23*2.2'),
(5,'0.143+4.22/3.4')

Select * from #temp1

Drop Table #temp1


Select 1 ID,0.1+0.26 [Value]
Union ALL
Select 2 ID,1.1+7.25-4.65 [Value]
Union ALL
Select 3 ID,2.1+6.24*3.3 [Value]
Union ALL
Select 4 ID,3.14+5.23*2.2 [Value]
Union ALL
Select 5 ID,0.143+4.22/3.4 [Value]
```

Can any one suggest me to solve this.

Comment: remove single quotes. and which db you are using ? `mysql` or `sql  server` or something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dynamic query`. Try this.

```
SELECT *,
       0 AS t
INTO   #pars_temp -- Intermediate table for parsing each row
FROM   #temp1

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max),
        @id  INT,
        @val VARCHAR(5000)

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1
             FROM   #pars_temp
             WHERE  t = 0)-- To check the existence of unparsed row 
  BEGIN
      SELECT TOP 1 @val = value,
                   @id = id
      FROM   #pars_temp
      WHERE  t = 0

      SET @sql ='update #temp1 set value  = ' + @val
                + ' where id = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @id) -- update the values

      EXEC Sp_executesql @sql

      UPDATE #pars_temp
      SET    t = 1
      WHERE  id = @id -- To remove the parsed row
  END

SELECT *
FROM   #temp1
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to use the function to calculate the value

Comment: @ManiMaranVasan - Maybe a procedure. You cannot use dynamic query inside function

Comment: Yes, initially i tried with procedure but i can't access the procedure in select statement so drop that concept and posted here.

Thanks Your query is working fine and but this same process have to use in difference procedure so can't reuse that same code like function.

Comment: @ManiMaranVasan - create a `User Defined Table type` and pass the table  to be updated through User Defined Table type to the `procedure`.

Comment: Can you please post another answer using user Defined Table function.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @ManiMaranVasan - No its not `user Defined Table function`. It is `User Defined Table type`. It is a new question

Comment: Instead of creating a temporary table, don't you think a cursor would be more effective ?